# UIImage zoom in center

Tags: ios, uiimage, zooming, cgimage

I have method that zooming UIImage

```
- (UIImage*)croppedImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image zoom:(CGFloat)zoom
{
    CGFloat zoomReciprocal = 1.0f / zoom;

    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(40, 40);
    CGRect croppedRect = CGRectMake(offset.x, offset.y, image.size.width * zoomReciprocal, image.size.height * zoomReciprocal);

    CGImageRef croppedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], croppedRect);

    UIImage* croppedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:croppedImageRef scale:[image scale] orientation:[image imageOrientation]];

    CGImageRelease(croppedImageRef);

    return croppedImage;
}
```

How to save image width and height after zooming?

Comment: You want to save image or width and height of image ?'

Comment: Just image width and height, for ex. image.size = 100, 100: [self croppedImageWithImage:image zoom:1.0]; after performing method image.size must be 100, 100. not scalling...

Answer (score 1):

To save zoomed image :

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

To save Image Size

```
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(croppedImage.size.width, croppedImage.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the  image width and height just create CGSize variable and save like below

```
CGSize croppedSize = croppedImage.size
```